# PANDAS: Getting NaN when multiplying values in different DFs

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting NaN as the result of the following operation:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'Y':['A','B','C'],'X':[1,2,3]})
df['X'] = df['X'].astype('float64')

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data={'Y':['A','B','C'],'X':[10,10,10]})
df2['X'] = df2['X'].astype('float64')

df['Z'] = df.loc[df['Y']=='B','X'] * df2.loc[df2['Y']=='C','X']
```

The idea is to assign the whole new 'Z' column.

What could I do to fix it?

tks

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add `values`

```
df.loc[df['Y']=='B','Z'] = df.loc[df['Y']=='B','X'].values * df2.loc[df2['Y']=='C','X'].values

df
   Y    X     Z
0  A  1.0   NaN
1  B  2.0  20.0
2  C  3.0   NaN
```

Comment: Can't I have the result assigned to the whole column 'Z' from df?

Comment: @Filipe where is your 'Z'

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this:

```
df['Z'] = 0
df['Z'] = df['Z'].apply(lambda x: df.loc[df['Y']=='B','X'] * df2.loc[df2['Y']=='C','X'].values)
```